# Compare two table row values ColdFusion?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have two queries and each query is outputted on the screen in separate table. Both quires have the same number of records but I would like to check if each field is equal if not I want to set different background color for that table row. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
<cfquery name="oldData" datasource="test">
    SELECT 
        old_id,
        old_userid,
        old_first,
        old_last,
        old_dob
  FROM OldTest
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="newData" datasource="test">
    SELECT 
        new_id,
        new_userid,
        new_first,
        new_last,
        new_dob
  FROM NewTest
</cfquery>
```

And here is code for both tables:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <table class="oldData">
                    <caption>Old Data</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>UserID</th>
                            <th>First</th>
                            <th>Last</th>
                            <th>DOB</th>
                        <tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <cfoutput query="oldData">
                            <tr>
                                <td>#old_id#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(old_userid)#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(old_first)#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(old_last)#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(old_dob)#</td>
                            </tr>
                        </cfoutput>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <table class="newData">
                    <caption>New Data</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>UserID</th>
                            <th>First</th>
                            <th>Last</th>
                            <th>DOB</th>
                        <tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <cfoutput query="newData">
                            <tr>
                                <td>#new_id#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(new_userid)#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(new_first)#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(new_last)#</td>
                                <td>#Trim(new_dob)#</td>
                            </tr>
                        </cfoutput>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I'm wondering if I should compare data rows before the output something like:

```
<cfif oldData.old_first[currentrow] NEQ newData.new_first[currentrow]>
    <cfset rowColor = "red">
</cfif>
```

Or there is better way to approach this. If anyone knows better way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would use looping:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#oldData.recordCount#" index="r">
    Question #oldData.old_id[r]# = #oldData.new_id[r]#? Answer: #oldData.old_id[r] eq oldData.new_id[r]#<br>
</cfloop>
```

You can wrap the loop around TRs and TDs if you desire.

This method also eliminates the need for a QofQ, which are resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a query of queries resembling this:

```
 select 'same' comparison, field1, field2, etc 
 from query1, query2
 where query1.someField = query2.someField
 union
 select 'different' comparison, field1, field2, etc 
 from query1
 where somefield not in (<cfqueryparam value="#valueList(query2.someField#") list = true>
```

Your table row colour can be specified with a ternary operator.

```
<tr bgcolor="#comparison is 'same' ? 'white' : 'red'#">
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand how compassion works in your example. Can you explain please?

Comment: Are you referring to the Q of Q or the `<tr>` tag?

Comment: tr tag in your answer above.

Comment: I included the term `ternary operator` so you would know what to google.

Comment: Why use a QoQ instead of a database query?